# LINQ: Count number of true booleans in multiple columns

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, count

I'm using LINQ to SQL to speed up delivery of a project, which it's really helping with. However I'm struggling with a few things I'm used to doing with manual SQL.

I have a **LINQ collection containing three columns, each containing a boolean value** representing whether an e-mail, mobile or address is availble.

I want to **write a LINQ query to give me an count of trues for each column**, so how many rows in the e-mail column are set to true (and the same for the other two columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a single object containing the results:

```
var result = new {
    HasEmailCount = list.Count(x => x.HasEmail),
    HasMobileCount = list.Count(x => x.HasMobile),
    HasAddressCount = list.Count(x => x.HasAddress)
};
```

Or using the aggregate function:

```
class Result
{
 public int HasEmail;
 public int HasAddress;
 public int HasMobile;
}

var x = data.Aggregate(
 new Result(),
 (res, next) => {
  res.HasEmail += (next.HasEmail ? 0 : 1);
  res.HasAddress += (next.HasAddress ? 0 : 1);
  res.HasMobile += (next.HasMobile ? 0 : 1);
  return res;
 }
);
```

`x` is of Type `Result` and contains the aggregated information. This can also be used for more compelx aggregations.

Comment: Two points -- 1) I don't believe you can modify the first parameter of the Aggregate function, it is read only.  2) You have your `0` and `1` reversed, you add 1 on false and 0 on true.  Other than that a very nice idea, but having to do a `new` on each element seems "not ideal" to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mobileCount = myTable.Count(user => user.MobileAvailable);
```

And so on for the other counts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
var emailCount = yourDataContext.YourTable.Count(r => r.HasEmail);
```

etc.

Comment: How do I get the Column Name (Group) : Count